# Passing parameters from Geometry Nodes of different objects

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a Geometry Node group named 'Main' where I defined a vector and connected it to the group output.

On another object I have a Geometry Node group named 'Sphere' where I want to position the sphere using the vector retrieved from the Group Input.

How can I link the position from the Group Output of the GN 'Main' to the Group Input of the GN 'Sphere' ?

[image]

The Geometry Nodes 'Main'

[image]

The Geometry Nodes 'Sphere'

[image]

Comment: Hello. Seems like you just need to add the modifier node as a node group and use a Set Position instead of Transform node, since you're working with a field and Transform only takes scalar values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Gorgious mentioned in the comments, the better solution would probably be just adding the 'Main' node group to Sphere node group:

[image]

You can also use drivers or [Application Handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) to control one property with another. You can do it with nodes in GN modifiers directly - just right-click some property and choose Copy as New Driver:

[image]

Then paste the driver the same way on the property you want to drive:

[image]

You will need to do that for each component of the vector in this case.

Comment: For the moment I prefer your first solution. Thank you so much ! :)

Answer (score 3):

As Martynas [shows](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294154/35559), there are various ways of doing the plumbing, here.  Another might be to make the attribute-carrying object available to the attribute-receiving modifier, by sampling.

Since this attribute is object-wide on the carrier (Cube), bearing no relation to its geometry, it could make sense to make the carrier an instance, and store the attribute on that:

[image]

The above version sets the attribute's name in the carrier's interface on the way out. (You wouldn't have to.. you could hardcode the name, if you wanted to.)

Once set, it can be picked up by another modifier, on another, receiving, object by sampling the named attribute from the carrier instance, made available with *Object Info*:

[image]

Again, what you choose to expose in the modifier interface is up to you.

[image]

Comment: This actually could sometimes make a nice alternative to drivers.. quickly copied to multiple objects..?

Comment: Thanks Robin for your solution too :D